# java.io.IOException: failure to login: No LoginModules configured for hadoop_simple

Tags: hadoop, talend

I'm trying to run my first Talend job from TAC.
I'm trying to call big data batch from a standard job.
It is running fine from the local cluster, but while running the same job from TAC i'm facing this error.

```
moment;pid;root_pid;father_pid;project;job;context;priority;type;origin;message;code
2017-02-13 07:54:29;20170213075427_jnxLB;20170213075427_jnxLB;20170213075427_jnxLB;ELT_3_0;CustomerDataLoad;hadoop;6;Java Exception;tRunJob_2;java.lang.RuntimeException:Child job returns 1. It doesn't terminate normally.
java.io.IOException: failure to login: No LoginModules configured for hadoop_simple
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:724)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:676)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:560)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.<init>(FileSystem.java:2784)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.<init>(FileSystem.java:2776)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2642)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:404)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getLocal(FileSystem.java:375)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.validateFiles(GenericOptionsParser.java:392)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.processGeneralOptions(GenericOptionsParser.java:288)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.parseGeneralOptions(GenericOptionsParser.java:479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.<init>(GenericOptionsParser.java:170)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.<init>(GenericOptionsParser.java:153)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:64)
    at elt_3_0.hbase_customertable_0_1.Hbase_customertable.runJobInTOS(Hbase_customertable.java:38664)
    at elt_3_0.hbase_customertable_0_1.Hbase_customertable.main(Hbase_customertable.java:38642)
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No LoginModules configured for hadoop_simple
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.init(LoginContext.java:272)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.<init>(LoginContext.java:389)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.newLoginContext(UserGroupInformation.java:450)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:696)
    ... 15 more
```

Am i missing any dependencies?
Any help can be appreciated.

Comment: since Talend is built on open source some problems are based on the underlying technology.  here is a posting outside the Talend world where someone solved same issue.  i hope it helps  https://community.mapr.com/thread/9240

Comment: I have seen this link, @ELaRoche

Comment: ok, the point is that the issue may not be Talend related per se, so you may have better luck solving it by searching on the underlying technology, vs Talend specific.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it,
by adding the property "`-Djava.security.auth.login.config`" in JVM props and pointed the property towards /opt/mapr/conf/mapr.login.conf.
So, in mapr.login.conf there is hadoop login class

```
/**
 * simple login, just get OS creds
 */
hadoop_simple {
  org.apache.hadoop.security.login.GenericOSLoginModule required;
  org.apache.hadoop.security.login.HadoopLoginModule required;
};
```

Which enables the user to submit applications to the server which all the proper modules.